# Can set operations be set-theoretically defined as functions? ( Is there any set that could be the domain of these functions?)

Tags: set-theory

Usually, a binary operation on a set A is defined as a function from the cartesian product of A with itself ( " A cross A") ( or, from a subset of this cartesian product) to A.

If binary set operations ( for ex.  union, intersection, etc.) were to be defined as functions, they would take as input ordered  pairs of sets, and these ordered pairs should " come from" the cartesian product of the set of all sets with itself.

But, in order this cartesian product to exist, **the set of all sets should first exist.**

So, can set operations be defined as functions? And, if it is not the case, what is their official status?

Comment: Words to live by: class functions.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137319/how-do-we-justify-functions-on-the-ordinals

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Thanks for this interesting link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right :

> we cannot use the cartesian product of the set of all sets with itself in order to define the basic set operations.

Using [Axiom schema of Separation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/#AxiZFC) we prove that:

> $\exists ! C \ \forall x \ (x \in C \leftrightarrow x \in A \land x \in B)$.

Thus, we may "enlarge" the basic set language introducing a new symbol $\cap$:

> $A \cap B = y \leftrightarrow \forall x \ (x \in y \leftrightarrow x \in A \land x \in B)$.

---

Similarly, but using in addition the *Union Axiom*, we prove that:

> $\exists ! C \ \forall x \ (x \in C \leftrightarrow x \in A \lor x \in B)$.

This justify the introduction of the new symbol $\cup$:

> $A \cup B = y \leftrightarrow \forall x \ (x \in y \leftrightarrow x \in A \lor x \in B)$.

---

Thus, what we have is a "recipe" that allows us to manufacture, for every pair of existing sets (i.e. sets whose existence has been already proved by the theory) a new set : their *union* (respectively: *intersection*).

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right about the set of all sets, which doesn't exist since it leads to contradictions. Such "sets" which are too large to actually be a set but still very nice to consider them as some sort of collection of objects are called [*proper classes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)). There are several axiom systems for set theory that make the notion of class explicit, e.g. [von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) axioms.

Ordinary functions $X \rightarrow Y$ are certain subsets of the cartesian product $X \times Y$. We can use the same idea to define class-functions: if $Set$ is the class of all sets, a class-function is a subset of $Set \times Set$. This way, $\cup,\cap,\times$ etc. (viewed as operations on sets) become class-functions.

Answer (score 1):

According to my restricted knowledge of sets and working in ZFC:

It might be that $\Phi(x,y,z)$ is a formula with $3$ free variables $x,y,z$ such that for every ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ there is exactly one $z$ with the property that $\Phi(x,y,z)$ is true.

For instance take for $\Phi(x,y,z)$ the formalization of the statement that $z=x\cup y$.

In this case $\Phi$ determines a proper class of ordered pairs $\langle\langle x,y\rangle,z\rangle$, but not a function.

This because a function is by definition a *set* of ordered pairs.

However, it can be recognized as an operation on sets.